How can I create a branch in my fork based off a branch in a different fork (of the same master)?
I have my own fork I’ve been working on for awhile:
https://github.com/udance4ever/batocera.linux/
I verified the work done in this branch of a fellow developer’s fork is something I wish to build upon:
https://github.com/bryanforbes/batocera.linux/tree/bryanforbes/macos-build
How do I create my own “Apple-build” branch in my fork that is based off of the above branch in a different fork?
Both forks have the same master:
https://github.com/batocera-linux/batocera.linux/
I’m well aware I could make a “fork of a fork” but I’m still going to run into the issue of how to merge any changes I make in the new fork back into my own original fork (as I don’t anticipate commits being pulled into master anytime soon)
If someone would like to suggest a different workflow that achieves the same goal, please feel welcome to!
What I’ve tried
This answer looked promising so I tried:
git fetch https://github.com/bryanforbes/batocera.linux.git bryanforbes/macos-build

which ends up fetching data into my repository:
remote: Enumerating objects: 48, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Total 48 (delta 24), reused 41 (delta 22), pack-reused 1 (from 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (48/48), 26.15 KiB | 704.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/bryanforbes/batocera.linux
 * branch                    bryanforbes/macos-build -> FETCH_HEAD
Fetching submodule buildroot
From https://github.com/batocera-linux/buildroot
   ce59a3e8ce..015766e5a6  br2-external -> origin/br2-external
From https://github.com/batocera-linux/buildroot
 * branch                  c5e38d806a062cd40ccc5c0f000370d9f3c65879 -> FETCH_HEAD

but when I try:
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories bryanforbes/macos-build

I get this error:
merge: bryanforbes/macos-build - not something we can merge

I also can’t seem to switch to the branch:
$ git checkout bryanforbes/macos-build
error: pathspec 'bryanforbes/macos-build' did not match any file(s) known to git

My thinking is if I am able to import the branch into my own repo, I’ll be able to merge the commits into an integration branch and go from there.

Have a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

@Adeva1 thank you so much for pointing me in a direction. I found an answer that looked relevant & edited my question to include what worked and didn’t work.

just a heads up I figured it out and posted my answer.  I ended up forking the fork, changing the remote origin and creating a new branch based on the desired branch & pushing this into my own fork. thanks again for yr help!

Make a fork of a fork:
git clone https://github.com/bryanforbes/batocera.linux

Switch to desired branch:
git checkout bryanforbes/macos-build

Create a new branch (based on desired branch):
git checkout -b Apple-build bryanforbes/macos-build

Change remote origin to your own fork:
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/udance4ever/batocera.linux.git

Push new branch to your fork (setting the upstream):
git push --set-upstream origin Apple-build

Result is a branch based on commits in a branch in a different fork and now tracked in your own fork:
https://github.com/udance4ever/batocera.linux/tree/Apple-build

After fetching, try : git checkout -b Apple-build bryanforbes/bryanforbes/macos-build 
this will create Apple-Build based what we just fetched,then you push Apple-Build your own repo (where origin is relevant to https://github.com/udance4ever/batocera.linux/)
if you want to get future updates from macos-build for example:
git fetch bryanforbes bryanforbes/macos-build
git checkout Apple-build
git rebase bryanforbes/bryanforbes/macos-build
git rebase --continue
git push origin Apple-build --force-with-lease

This will fetch new commits compare your own branch to the updated repo, then rebaseing and using --continue switch again to resolve conflicts if any, and finally wil push everything back to your repo
Ref (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):


    $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>

    You could omit <branch>, in which case the command degenerates to "check out the current branch", which is a glorified no-op with rather expensive side-effects to show only the tracking information, if it exists, for the current branch.
git checkout -b|-B <new-branch> [<start-point>]

    Specifying -b causes a new branch to be created as if git-branch[1] were called and then checked out. In this case you can use the --track or --no-track options, which will be passed to git branch. As a convenience, --track without -b implies branch creation; see the description of --track below.

    If -B is given, <new-branch> is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of


I tried the command you suggested and got fatal: 'bryanforbes/bryanforbes/macos-build' is not a commit and a branch 'Apple-build' cannot be created from it - I also tried git checkout -b Apple-build bryanforbes/macos-build and got the same error.  However I did go to the clone I have of this developer’s fork and was able to create the Apple-build branch & now trying to figure out if I can change the remote to push this branch to my own fork.

Did you run the command from a valid repo directory ?
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).```

This is the result of running it on a non repo dir. I am cloning it now to a blank repo to try and recreate the steps

I posted an answer of what worked.  thank you so much for the hint and your help!
